# Google Map set as default launcher using "Always", how to get that setting while click on map again

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created Cross- Platform Application using xamarin- forms for Android app, here I am facing issue to get default launcher for the particular app, or may be terminology is different for "default launcher", so basically this popup which I don't want to display next time to user if user has already selected any one map as default by using "Always" (as shown in the Image), for that I need to get that whether particular app is set as default or not, how to get that, I have tried getprefferedactivities and resolveinfo, nothing works for me, Please can anyone suggest?

Always Open Description

[image]

Comment: Image attached in Always Open Description

Answer (score 0):

The default Android behavior is that it asks the user if multiple apps can handle a user request like open a web page. If the user chooses "Just once" no default app is specified and Android will ask again.

If the user choose "Always" the dialog will not be displayed again until the than specified default app is removed and multiple apps are still available. If only one app is able to handle the user request the dialog will also not appear.